# Can't find System.Net.Http.Formatting dll

Tags: .net, gac, visual-studio-2015

I have a clean installation of Visual Studio 2015 RC.  I don't have VS2013 installed.

I loaded a solution and the `System.Net.Http.Formatting` reference is broken, when I try to add the reference I don't find it in the GAC.

Comment: I'm with you.  Trying to make a `PostAsJsonAsync` call to an API and can't add a reference.  Is there a new way of doing it or a solution?  I want to start a bounty but I don't want a 'browse to it manually to add the reference' as an answer.

Comment: I wouldn't accept an answer like that, but that was what I ended up doing.

Comment: Come to find out, they moved `System.Net.Http.Formatting` into the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client nuget package.  I don't like having to reference all of the libraries that come with this but it is the only way to check in your code without having to check in a binary.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

After some reading/searching online I found that once there was a `System.Net.Http.Formatting` package which now appears to be discontinued as one if it's dependencies can no longer be found on  nuget `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client (>= 2.0.20710 && < 2.1.0)`. As of right now what you should do is just install `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` (I tried version `5.2.3` and it works fine). The Assembly `System.Net.Http.Formatting, version=5.2.3.0` is included in the package, though I don't know if it's the only one bundled there.