# Simple C# RESTfull client

Tags: c#, .net, xml, rest, client

I am trying to consume RESTful service with as simple as possible C# utility. Response is given as XML and I just want to put it into string and later "pretty print it" and save it on disk. For now I am trying just to get proper response. Service is third party and it works OK, tested it many times in browser and java client. In C# utility authorization went OK and as far as I can tell I see in debugger in response object that

> StatusCode    OK  System.Net.HttpStatusCode

and

> StatusDescription "OK" string

but looks like response itself is empty? String Xml which has to hold response as String is empty (not null but empty). What do I do wrong?

Here is complete code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {

        public static void SetBasicAuthHeader(WebRequest request, String userName, String userPassword)
        {
            string authInfo = userName + ":" + userPassword;
            authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));
            request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + authInfo;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = null;
            HttpWebResponse response = null;
            String Xml;

            // Create the web request  
            request = WebRequest.Create("https://some.web.services.com?id='1234'&param1='1'&param2='2'") as HttpWebRequest;
            SetBasicAuthHeader(request, "userName", "userPassword");

            // Get response
            response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

            // Get the response stream  
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

            Xml = reader.ReadToEnd();

            // Console xml output  
            Console.WriteLine(Xml); //see if we get the xml response
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what's "on the wire"?

Comment: why are you using `WebRequest` instead of `HttpClient`?

Comment: @Amit I don't know what you mean, but if you are asking me what should be response then it is just simple XML with few elements. It's some services for catalog of books, papers etc., so title, author, publishing date, nothing special

Comment: I'm asking what actually goes through the network. What the driver sees, not what your app sees...

Comment: @Luiso because I found such example either here or on the web :) Besides that although I have .net 4.5 VS can't import WebRequest - I don't know why?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen some weird behavior with manually using Authorization header; try this:

```
    using System.Net; // contains HttpRequestHeader enum

    public static void SetBasicAuthHeader(WebRequest request, String userName, String userPassword)
    {
        string authInfo = userName + ":" + userPassword;
        authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(authInfo));
        string authHeader = string.Format("Basic {0}", authInfo);
        request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = authHeader;
    }
```

Comment: This code doesn't appear to have any affect on `request.Headers`.  I think it needs to do some thing to `request.Headers` for it to work.

Comment: @AlastairBrown current version does update request.Headers :)

Comment: Actually it gone worse: 
Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at ConsoleApplication3.Program.Main(String[] args) in Visual Studio 2013\Projects
lication3\Program.cs:line 47

Comment: @NenadBulatovic Did you use latest version (which sets request.Headers) ?

Comment: @DmitriyKhaykin if by that you mean which .NET I am using then it is 4.5

Comment: No, I meant which version of my answer ... I updated it as it was missing a crucial line (the last line you now see `request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = authHeader;`) and I wanted to make sure that you tried my answer with that line in the code.

Comment: @DmitriyKhaykin now it doesn't throw exception but still empty response.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `HttpClient` what you are trying to do, your code should be something like this:

```
static void Main(...)
{
    var token = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{user}:{pwd}"));
    using(var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", token);

        // here you could also use await right after GetAsync but since a Console application I use this instead
        var response = client.GetAsync(url).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        // again the await could help here
        var xml = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        Console.WriteLine(xml);
    }
}
```

you could also have also gotten a `Stream` instead of a `string` by calling: `response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();` and from there use it as you want, if you want to read in chunks or buffering to optimize.

Hope this helps. Also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30400358/cant-find-system-net-http-formatting-dll/3528038) it could be useful  as it contains several extensions to convert between popular formats used in REST, although I don't know for sure if it could help you here as well with `xml`.